# docker run git checkout doesn't fetch changes in the branch?

Tags: docker

Why `RUN git checkout -b mybranch` switch to the branch but the content remain the one fetched from the `master` branch?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of Docker is that it only rebuilds the part of an image that has changed. It has no way of knowing that the content in the repo has changed, all it knows is that is already has a cached image "slice" for this step in the Dockerfile. So it uses the image it previously built.

As Mark notes, you can force a regeneration using --no-cache. Another option is to have a source code container that is always built using --no-cache which you add volumes to and then use that code via those volumes in a different container (look at 'volumes from' for docker-compose). Then you always get the changes in the repo, as it is built every time from scratch. You may want to look into 'docker-compose' for this sort of work.

When you run docker build look carefully at the output. When it has a cached version of a step it will say as much. When it has to build it, it will also note that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your build with the "--no-cache" option?

I'd also recommend reading the following:

https://ryanfb.github.io/etc/2015/07/29/git_strategies_for_docker.html

Finally, do you really need to run git within your build? Personally I use Jenkins that runs my build within a workspace that is separately checked out from git.

Comment: I get the same error! `ImportError: No module named multifile`, but I know this `multifile` module exists in the branch!